# not able to start nightwatch for testing WebRTC

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webrtc, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am new to selenium. Now, I am stumbled upon Nightwatch.js for testing WebRTC. I am trying out this [link](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch-webrtcdemo) to start. Now I have set up accordingly. Now when I try to run, I am getting the following error

```
 Starting selenium server... There was an error while starting the Selenium server:

 Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -host
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:219)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:147)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:73)
```

Following other links. I ran the following command

```
java -Dwebriver.chrome.driver="./bin/chromedriver" -jar bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar
```

And the `selenium server` started, but still when I run the test from `Nightwatch`, the error exists, Please help!